# Superposition in state space equation with multiple harmonics in the inputs

Tags: control

I have a question related to the superposition in state space equation. Suppose I have a state space equation below
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}X = AX + B\begin{vmatrix}
u_1(t)\\
u_2(t) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
where X is the state vector, A, B are constant matrixes. u is the input time varying signals.

Now assume u can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
u_1(t) = c_1\cos(w_1t)+c_2\cos(w_2t)\\
u_2(t) = d_1\cos(w_1t)+d_2\cos(w_2t)\\
\end{equation}
where c1, c2, d1, d2 are constant coefficients, and w1 and w2 are different.

Can I rewrite the state space equation into the following two equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}X_1 = AX_1 + B\begin{vmatrix}
c_1\cos(w_1t)\\
d_1\cos(w_1t) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}X_2 = AX_2 + B\begin{vmatrix}
c_2\cos(w_2t)\\
d_2\cos(w_2t) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

And then I solve for time-domain steady state expression for X1 and X2. The final time domain expression for X would be
\begin{equation}
X = X_1+X_2
\end{equation}

Is there anything wrong with this method?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct!

It's the magic of linear systems.

Find it also on [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle#Additive_state_decomposition).

Comment: One does need to ensure that the initial conditions also satisfy $X(t_0)=X_1(t_0)+X_2(t_0)$.

Comment: Yes, definitely, which basically enforces a constraint on one of the substates $X_i(t_0)$ since we're initially given with $X(t_0)$.